# template deduction and explicitly supplied types for parameter packs

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-functions, pack, template-argument-deduction

I will simplify and shorten this question to facilitate an answer.

The essential is:

why this code is compiled and executed

```
  # include <iostream>
  template <class A> class Goofy {};

  template <int N, template <class> class B, class A, int ... K, class ... Z>
  void f ( A a, B<A> b, Z ... z )
  {
   std::cout << "I'm executed" << std::endl;
  }

  int main()
  {
   Goofy<int> goofy;
   f<1, Goofy, int, 2, 3, 4>(2,goofy,1.3,'a',1.f);
   }
```

while the following isn't?

```
  # include <iostream>
  template <class A> class Goofy {};

  template <int N, template <class> class B, class A, int ... K, class ... Z>
  void f ( A a, B<A> b, Z ... z )
  {
   std::cout << "I'm executed" << std::endl;
  }

  int main()
  {
   Goofy<int> goofy;
   f<1, Goofy, int, 2, 3, 4, double, char, float>(2,goofy,1.3,'a',1.f);
   }
```

The only difference is the explicit and **consistent** supply of the types
which instantiate the pack `Z`.

I didn't think that this would end in a compilation error, moreover with
a diagnostic telling *template deduction/substitution failed* when, IMHO,
there wouldn't be any need for a deduction.

Can anybody explain this to me?

I used compilers GNU 7.3.1 and *clang* 4.0.1 and both behave the same, so I fear there is something deeply wrong in my reasoning... but I cannot find what.

Answer (score 3):

Your code can be reduced to:

```
template <int... N, class T>
auto foo(T) {};

auto test()
{
    foo<1, 2, 3>(4); // OK
    foo<1, 2, 3, int>(4); // ERROR
}
```

The reason is that variadic arguments are greedy. That's why they need to be last when explicitly stating them.

When you write `foo<1, 2, 3>(4);`:

- `1, 2, 3` are matched against `int... N` -> `N` deduced to `1, 2, 3` - >OK
- then the `T` is deduced from the function argument i.e. `4` to `int` -> OK

When you write `foo<1, 2, 3, int>(4);`:

- `1, 2, 3, int` are matched against `int... N` -> error

Comment: What has suggested such a greediness of packs? When there is, as in your example, or also in mine, a NON-type pack immediately followed by a type or even a pack of types, why the compiler could not detect a boundary to stop the parsing of NON-type parameters? Everybody should see that "int" is completely different from a constexpr integer value.

Comment: @GSi because that's the grammar of C++. And it's like that most likely because the cost of the added complexity to deal with this specific case wasn't justified.